# How to give path/url for background image in tailwind?

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css, background-image, web-frontend

I'm using Tailwind in my React Project. I want to add a background image in a div but it shows the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../icons/blog-hero-1.png' in 'C:\Users\DELL\frontend-development\aidhumanity-practice-2\src'
```

I'm adding tailwind class

```
bg-[url('../../icons/blog-hero-1.png')]
```

for adding background image and url is relative to the current file and also it's working when added normal image through:

```
import Hero from "../../icons/blog-hero-1.png"
<div>
  <img src={Hero} className="h-full rounded-3xl"></img>
</div>
```

Can anyone guide how to give the correct url?
**Note**: I've added a codesandbox example here as well for better demonstration in which I've tried to import background image in "Homepage.js" but it's not working.
https://codesandbox.io/s/background-image-wl9104?file=/src/components/Homepage.js

Comment: can you please let us know which version of tailwind css you are using? I believe the feature of using background image as Arbitrary values is introduced in the v3.2.6.

Comment: @Sam My package.josn indicates "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"... Can you please confirm whether this version of tailwind supports this feature or not?

Comment: it working for 3.2.4. I have checked. Well you might need to rebuild the tailwind css or restart the server once to see the images. I have created a sample for you in tailwind playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/e4az4dl6ok . Its version is 3.2.6 but the implementation is same. I have noticed that I needed to add the 'whitespace-pre' in my tailwind class. Hope it helps.

Comment: have you tried using unsplash inside url() like @SamPhillemon tailwind playground example? is it work? just to make sure your tailwind version and setup is right

Answer (score 0):

Well you can achieve the same result with the below approach as well:

In your `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'hero': "url('../../icons/blog-hero-1.png')"
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

You can simply mention `bg-hero` in you class to implement.

Comment: Tried this but not working.

Comment: Well Its working on my end. I have created a sample for the above approach: https://play.tailwindcss.com/dp4DPVlA5w . Please have a look and see if you are missing anything. Else please share your code online editor or something to give you better answer.

Comment: ! here you can see what I'm trying to do...https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-wl9104?file=/src/components/Homepage.js... I've added a background image in Homepage.js which isn't showing. please have a look.